# How to estimate $\sum_{n=1}^{M} \frac{1}{n^{\beta}}$ for $\beta>0$ and fix $M>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Fix $M \in N$ and $\beta>0.$ Can we prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{M} \frac{1}{n^{\beta}}\sim \begin{cases} 1 \quad if  \ \beta>1\\
\log M \quad if \ \beta=1\\
M^{1-\beta} \quad \ if \beta<1 \end{cases}$$

Note. I know that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\beta}}$ is convergent if $\beta>1$ and divergent if $\beta=1.$

Comment: Abel's summation formula should be able to prove this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\beta>1$ the series converges and $$\sum_{n=1}^M\frac{1}{n^{\beta}}\underset{M\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\zeta(\beta)$$
If $\beta\leqslant 1$, since $x\rightarrow\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing on $(0,+\infty)$ we have
$$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*,\int_n^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^{\beta}}\leqslant\frac{1}{n^{\beta}} \text{ and }\forall n\geqslant 2,\frac{1}{n^{\beta}}\leqslant\int_{n-1}^n\frac{dx}{x^{\beta}} $$
Summing this gives us
$$ \frac{1}{M^{\beta}}+\int_1^M\frac{dx}{x^{\beta}}\leqslant \sum_{n=1}^M\frac{1}{n^{\beta}}\leqslant1+\int_1^M\frac{dx}{x^{\beta}} $$
Since $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\frac{1}{n^{\beta}}$ diverges we have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^M\frac{1}{n^{\beta}}\underset{M\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\int_1^M\frac{dx}{x^{\beta}} $$
When $\beta=1$ we have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^M\frac{1}{n}\underset{M\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\ln M $$
when $\beta<1$ we have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^M\frac{1}{n^{\beta}}\underset{M\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{M^{1-\beta}}{1-\beta} $$

**EDIT :** Study of $$S_M:=\sum_{\underset{1\leqslant \|n\|_2\leqslant M}{n\in\mathbb{Z}^d}}\frac{1}{\|n\|_2^{\beta}}$$
for $M\geqslant 1$ and $\beta>0$

First notice that $$ S_M=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor M^2\rfloor}\frac{u_k}{k^{\beta/2}} $$
where $u_k:=\text{card}\{n\in\mathbb{Z}^d\ |\ \|n\|_2^2=k\}$. For $r\geqslant 0$ let $$ N(r):=\text{card}\{n\in\mathbb{Z}^d\ |\ \|n\|_2\leqslant r\} $$
For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}^d$ such that $\|n\|_2\leqslant r$, we consider a unite hypercube centered around $n$ so that $N(r)$ is the volume of the reunion of these hypercubes. According to Pythagorean theorem, the reunion of these hybercubes is in between the hyperspheres of radius $r-\frac{\sqrt{d}}{2}$ and $r+\frac{\sqrt{d}}{2}$ (this is because the length of the longest diagonal of such an hypercube is $\sqrt{d}$). Here is the case $r=2$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ :

[image]

Thus if $\mathcal{V}_d$ is the volume of the hypershere of radius $1$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, we have
$$ \mathcal{V}_d\left(r-\frac{\sqrt{d}}{2}\right)^d\leqslant N(r)\leqslant\mathcal{V}_d\left(r+\frac{\sqrt{d}}{2}\right)^d $$
It follows that $N(r)=\mathcal{V}_d r^d+\mathcal{O}(r^{d-1})$. But $$u_k=N(\sqrt{k})-N(\sqrt{k-1})=\frac{d}{2}\mathcal{V}_d k^{\frac{d-2}{2}}+\mathcal{O}\left(k^{\frac{d-1}{2}}\right)$$
This leads us to $u_k=\mathcal{O}\left(k^{\frac{d-1}{2}}\right)$, this means that
$$ \frac{u_k}{k^{\beta/2}}=\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{k^{\frac{\beta-d+1}{2}}}\right) $$
Thus the series converges if $\frac{\beta-d+1}{2}>1$ that is to say $\beta>d+1$. We can do better, for instance with $d=1$ we have the convergence of the series if $\beta>2$ and we already know it converges if and only if $\beta>1$. In fact if we prove that $u_k\underset{k\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{d}{2}\mathcal{V}_d k^{\frac{d-2}{2}}$ then $$\frac{u_k}{k^{\beta/2}}\underset{k\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{1}{k^{\frac{\beta-d+2}{2}}}$$ and it would converge if and only if $\beta>d$. However it does not seem very clear because in the case $d=2$ we know that $u_k$ is pretty unstable because of Fermat's theorem on sum of two squares. I still belive that the series converges if and only if $\beta>d$ though. If we suppose that the following equivalent
$$ u_k\underset{k\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{d}{2}\mathcal{V}_d k^{\frac{d-2}{2}} $$
is true, then if $\beta\leqslant d$, the series diverges and thus
$$ S_M\underset{M\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{d}{2}\mathcal{V}_d\int_1^{M^2}\frac{dx}{x^{\frac{\beta-d+2}{2}}} $$
One can show that $\mathcal{V}_d=\frac{\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{d}{2}\right)}$ so that if $\beta=d$, we have
$$ S_M\underset{M\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{d\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{d}{2}\right)}\ln(M) $$
and if $\beta<d$ we have
$$ S_M\underset{M\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{2d\pi^{d/2}M^{d-\beta}}{(d-\beta)\Gamma\left(1+\frac{d}{2}\right)} $$

**EDIT :** $x\mapsto\frac{1}{\|x\|_2^{\beta}}$ is decreasing on $(0,+\infty)^d$, thus we have
$$ \int_{[n_1,n_1+1]\times\ldots\times[n_d,n_d+1]}\frac{dx}{\|x\|_2^{\beta}}\leqslant\frac{1}{\|n\|_2^{\beta}}\leqslant\int_{[n_1-1,n_1]\times\ldots\times[n_d-1,n_d]}\frac{dx}{\|x\|_2^{\beta}} $$
Summing this gives us that $$ \sum_{\underset{1\leqslant\|n\|_2\leqslant M}{n\in\mathbb{N}^d}}\frac{1}{\|n\|_2^{\beta}}<+\infty\iff\int_{\mathcal{H}_d}\frac{dx}{\|x\|_2^{\beta}}<+\infty $$
where $\mathcal{H}_d=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_d)\in[0,+\infty)^d\ |\ \exists i\in[\![1,d]\!],x_i\geqslant 1\}$. Since $$S_M=2^d\sum_{\underset{1\leqslant\|n\|_2\leqslant M}{n\in\mathbb{N}^d}}\frac{1}{\|n\|_2^{\beta}}$$
the series $S_M$ converges if and only if
$$ \int_{\mathcal{H}_d}\frac{dx}{\|x\|_2^{\beta}}<+\infty $$
However for all $M\geqslant 1$, if
$$ \mathcal{H}_d(M):=\{(x_1,\ldots,x_d)\in[0,M]^d\ |\ \exists i\in[\![1,d]\!],x_i\geqslant 1\} $$
we have
$$ \overline{B_{\|\cdot\|_2}(0,M)}\subset\mathcal{H}_d\cup[0,1]^d\subset\overline{B_{\|\cdot\|_2}(0,M\sqrt{d})} $$
thus using hyperspherical coordinates, we have
$$ \mathscr{J}_d\int_1^M\frac{d\rho}{\rho^{\beta-d+1}}-1\leqslant\int_{\mathcal{H}_d(M)}\frac{dx}{\|x\|_2^{\beta}}\leqslant\mathscr{J}_d\int_1^{M\sqrt{d}}\frac{d\rho}{\rho^{\beta-d+1}}-1 $$
where $$\mathscr{J}_d=\prod_{j=1}^{d-2}\int_0^{\pi}(\sin\theta_j)^{d-j-1}d\theta_j\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(\theta_{d-1})d\theta_{d-1}$$
This leads us to
$$ \int_{\mathcal{H}_d}\frac{dx}{\|x\|_2^{\beta}}<+\infty\iff\beta-d+1>1\iff\beta>d $$
and thus $S_M$ converges if and only if $\beta>d$.

Comment: Thanks.  Can say something  for the higher dimensional analogue of this question? I mean if consider: $\sum_{1\leq |n|\leq M} \frac{1}{|n|^{\beta}}$ and $n\in \mathbb Z^d.$

Comment: I edited my answer, I did what I could do.

Comment: Thanks. Can we invoke [integral test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15360/does-the-integral-test-work-on-higher-dimensions) to conclude the series is convergent for $\beta>d$?

Comment: Yes you are right, I edited my answer.